# In Isaiah 1:3 LXX, what is "τὸν κτησάμενον"?

Tags: word-study, isaiah, septuagint

The word is not found in BDAG because it is only used in the OT, not in the NT.However, this is what the other Lexicons have:

[https://logeion.uchicago.edu/κτάομαι](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/%CE%BA%CF%84%CE%AC%CE%BF%CE%BC%CE%B1%CE%B9)

> [Isa 1:3 LXX] (3) ἔγνω βοῦς τὸν **κτησάμενον** καὶ ὄνος τὴν φάτνην τοῦ κυρίου αὐτοῦ Ισραηλ δέ με οὐκ ἔγνω καὶ ὁ λαός με οὐ συνῆκεν
>
> [Isa 1:3 ESV] (3) The ox knows its **owner**, and the donkey its master's crib, but Israel does not know, my people do not understand."

Answer (score 3):

κτησάμενον is a participle conjugated (in the aorist tense, middle voice) from the verb κτάομαι. The verb κτάομαι does indeed occur in the Greek New Testament,<sup>1</sup> and it is also found in BDAG.<sup>2</sup> It is **the perfect tense conjugation of κτάομαι** (as noted later in this answer by Wilke/Thayer) **that does not occur in the Greek NT**.

According to LSJ on the verb κτάομαι,<sup>3</sup>

[image: LSJ, p. 1001, I., 1.]

also,

[image: LSJ, p. 1001, κτάομαι, II., 2.]

Granted, κτησάμενον is conjugated in the aorist tense, while κεκτημένος is conjugated in the perfect tense.<sup>4</sup> Nevertheless, it seems like a suitable translation of the Hebrew word קֹנֵהוּ (*konehu*).<sup>5</sup>

According to Wilke (trans. Thayer),<sup>6</sup>

[image: Thayer, κτάομαι, p.363]

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Matt. 10:9; Luke 18:12, 21:19; Acts 1:18, 8:20, 22:28; 1 Thes. 4:4
<sup>2</sup> BDAG, p. 572
<sup>3</sup> LSJ, p. 1001
<sup>4</sup> According to Rahlfs’ ed. of the LXX, there are no textual variants for Isa. 1:3.
<sup>5</sup> conjugated from the verb קָנָה (*kana*)
<sup>6</sup> Wilke (trans. Thayer), p. [363](https://books.google.com/books?id=7wVNDAjFkRoC&pg=PA363#v=onepage&q&f=false)

#### References

Arndt, William; Bauer, Walter; Danker, Frederick William. *A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament and Other Early Christian Literature.* 3rd ed. Chicago: U of Chicago P, 2000.

Liddell, Henry George; Scott, Robert; et al. *A Greek-English Lexicon.* 9th ed. with revised supplement. Oxford: Clarendon, 1996.

Wilke, Christian Gottlob. [*A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament: Being Grimm Wilke’s Clavis Novi Testamenti.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=7wVNDAjFkRoC) Trans. Thayer, Joseph Henry. Ed. Grimm, Carl Ludwig Wilibald. Rev. ed. New York: American Book, 1889.